# How are current and voltage out of phase in capacitive circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, electrical-engineering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Physical explanation for capacitive circuit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48311/physical-explanation-for-capacitive-circuit)

We say that in capacitive circuit, the voltage and current are out of phase. Current is 90 (degrees) ahead of voltage. What is the physical explanation for this effect? How can current flow through a capacitive circuit when voltage is zero i.e. when voltage has a phase angle of 0 and current has a phase angle of 90?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48311/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Looks the same to me, but I feel like the answer wasn't very good. What's the protocol -- answer the older question, or the newer one?

Comment: @thatnerd: One should in principle always answer the oldest duplicate.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/55625